# How can I pass two "unbounded" arrays to a shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to update a *Shader Storage Buffer Object*

```
layout(binding = 0) buffer ssbo_per_frame
{
    uint n;
    float first[], second[];
};
```

on a per-frame basis. I've tried the following:

```
GLuint ssbo;
GLuint n = /* ... */;

std::size_t const size = /* ... */;
std::vector<float> first(size), second(size);

void init()
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &ssbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
    glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint) + 2 * size * sizeof(float), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}

void display()
{
    //
    // Modify 'first' and 'second
    //
    // ...

    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
    glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, size, &first[0]);
    glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, size, data_size, &second[0]);
}
```

**Questions:** Is `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` the correct usage specifier? Should I really use `glBufferSubData` to update the buffer? Do I need to use `GLfloat` instead of `float`?

> And most importantly: Does this even work? I assume not, since OpenGL doesn't know the sizes of `first` and `second`. So, if that's not working, what should I do instead? Creating two different Buffer Objects?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I pass two “unbounded” arrays to a shader?

You don't; not in a single SSBO.

The only member of an SSBO that can be unbounded is the last one. And since there can only be a single last member, only one member of an SSBO can be unbounded.

Also, there's *really* no point in passing the length. You can ask for the length of any array in your shader with the `.length()` method, even for unbounded members of an SSBO. The only difference is that for unbounded buffer variables, the length will not be a compile-time constant.

> So, if that's not working, what should I do instead? Creating two different Buffer Objects?

If the two arrays have the same length, then you can pass them as an unbounded array of structs. If the two arrays have different lengths, then they must be different shader storage blocks.

How many buffer objects you use is *irrelevant*. There's no rule that says that you can't bind the same buffer to two different shader storage block definitions. You could even overlap their contents if you like.